# Why is my try and catch stuck in a loop?

Tags: java, while-loop, try-catch

I want the user to enter integers into an array.  I have this loop I wrote which has a try and catch in it, in case a user inserts a non integer. There's a boolean variable which keeps the loop going if is true. This way the user will be prompted and prompted again.

Except, when I run it, it gets stuck in a loop where it repeats "Please enter # " and "An Integer is required" without letting the user input a new number. I reset that number if an exception is caught. I don't understand.

```
import java.util.*;
public class herp
{
    //The main accesses the methods and uses them.
    public static void main (String[] args)
    { 
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Hello and welcome!\n");
        System.out.print("This program stores values into an array"+" and prints them.\n");
        System.out.println("Please enter how many numbers would like to store:\n");
        int arraysize = scan.nextInt();

        int[]   mainarray = new int[arraysize+1];
        int     checkint  = 0;
        boolean notint    = true;
        int     prompt    = 1;

        while (prompt < mainarray.length)
        {
            // Not into will turn true and keep the loop going if the user puts in a
            // non integer. But why is it not asking the user to put it a new checkint?
            while(notint)
            {
                try
                {
                    notint = false;
                    System.out.println("Please enter #"+ prompt); 
                    checkint = scan.nextInt();
                } 
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    System.out.println("An integer is required." + 
                                       "\n Input an integer please"); 
                    notint   = true;
                    checkint = 1;
                    //See, here it returns true and checkint is reset.
                }      
            }
            mainarray[prompt] = checkint;
            System.out.println("Number has been added\n");
            prompt++;
            notint = true;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Has `scan` been initialized? You could very much be getting a `NullPointerException` on `scan`. Your catch statement is too broad, narrow it down to what you want to catch or it will hide bugs in your code.

Comment: Scan has been initialized, yes, I'll update the code.

Comment: Try printing the stack trace for your exception, it might not be what you expect. Also, try catching `NumberFormatException` for what you seem to need.

Comment: Gnargh, and there goes our formatting. PLEASE don't ovverride edits ;)

Comment: I tried cleaning up the indents to make it look clearer.

Comment: BTW, class should really be named `Herp`, convention is to always use uppercase :D

Comment: ^Yeah but I'm TRYING to catch exceptions. The idea is that I want to check for non-int inputs and insure that only ints are put in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once the scanner has thrown an `InputMismatchException` it cannot continue to be used. If your input is not reliable, instead of using `scanner.nextInt()` use `scanner.next()` to obtain a `String` then convert the string to an int.

Replace:

```
checkint = scan.nextInt();
```

With:

```
String s = scan.next();
checkint = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

Comment: Yeah, but if it starts out as a string; then couldn't the user just add any letters without it catching the non-int?

Comment: Yes, the `Integer.parseInt(s)` ensures the string can be parsed as a integer before it's accepted. If it can't, an exception is thrown and your message "An integer is required..." will be shown and they'll have to re-enter.

Comment: So I would have to use `scanner.next()`, then convert to integer with `Integer.parseInt` outside of the inner loop?

Comment: No, inside it. Replace that one line with the two I wrote. It will work, I assure you!

Comment: You could even combine the two lines into: `checkint = Integer.parseInt(scan.next());`

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected it like below. I don't rely on exception, but check if the next Scanner input is int (using hasNextInt()). If not int, just consume Scanner token and wait for the next user input. 
Looks like it is working, apart from 0 being inserted as a first array element, because you started indexing prompt from 1.

```
public class Herp {

    //The main accesses the methods and uses them.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Hello and welcome!\n");
        System.out.print("This program stores values into an array" + " and prints them.\n");
        System.out.println("Please enter how many numbers would like to store:\n");
        int arraysize = scan.nextInt();

        int[] mainarray = new int[arraysize + 1];
        int checkint = 0;
        boolean notint = true;
        int prompt = 1;

        while (prompt < mainarray.length) {
            while (notint) {
                notint = false;
                System.out.println("Please enter #" + prompt);
                // check if int waits for us in Scanner
                if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
                    checkint = scan.nextInt();
                } else {
                    // if not, consume Scanner token
                    scan.next(); 
                    System.out.println("An integer is required."
                        + "\n Input an integer please");
                    notint = true;
                }
            }
            mainarray[prompt] = checkint;
            System.out.println("Number has been added\n");
            prompt++;
            notint = true;
        }

        for (int i : mainarray) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I originally was writing this with if else, but I was getting this error. I'm trying to remember what it was called. discriminator predetermined? Something like that, it had a problem with the int. I'm not sure how you are doing it in the else statement.